# Ellipsis(...) is not working for single word

Tags: ellipsis, tibco-gi

I have set the following style sheet as value template for column of the grid in general interface (TIBCO GI) for text ellipsis

```
white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

It is working for sentences / more than one word. it is not working for single word.

Please help me to fix this out.

-Sridhar

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/CDRfq/)

I was able to get the ellipsis to show with only one word.  Try setting the overflow:hidden;.

I do want to add that I don't have TIBCO, so I couldn't test it in there, but this is a proof that it does work outside of it.